# Implementing classes with null safety enabled causes compilation error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

A bunch of the classes I implemented (for mocking purposes) without null safety have compilation errors now. Take this example:

```
class MockProvider extends Mock implements Provider<String>{}
```

This throws the error:

```
'Object.toString' ('String Function()') isn't a valid concrete implementation of
'Diagnosticable.toString' ('String Function({DiagnosticLevel minLevel})').
dart(invalid_implementation_override)
```

Mocking Firestore does something similar:

```
class MockFirestore extends Mock implements FirebaseFirestore {}
```

This creates the following error:

```
'Object.==' ('bool Function(Object)') isn't a valid concrete 
implementation of 'FirebaseFirestore.==' ('bool Function(dynamic)')
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using Mockito 5.0.0, and have you read its [null-safety instructions](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md)?

Comment: I’m using mock tail, but this seems to be beyond mocking. Implementing classes that override equality doesn’t work in general.

Comment: What do you mean that "Implementing classes that override equality doesn't work in general"?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: I suppose using mocks to illustrate was a bad idea, I'll create a new more descriptive question.